# should there be a getopt tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I just answered a question about `getopt` and then edited it to remove some irrelevant tags.  I also wanted to add a `getopt` tag but it wouldn't let me because it's too similar to `getopts`.

`getopt` is not the same as `getopts`.   `getopts` is a shell built-in.  `getopt` is a standalone executable in the [util-linux](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) package.  It's not compatible with `getopts` and adds several features that `getopts` doesn't have (like `--long` option support, and argument re-ordering).

Anyway, the error message suggested that I post here to ask if it should be created.  So I have.  IMO there should be such a tag, for the same reason that, e.g., we have separate `apache-httpd` and `nginx` and `lighttpd` etc tags - they might all do basically the same job, but they're completely different programs with incompatible configurations.   The `getopt` tag's description should clearly state that it's for the external program, not the shell built-in (the `getopts` tag states it's for the shell built-in).

NOTE: There is a generic `options` tag.  I think merging `getopts` into that would be a bad idea because it's probably not what people would search for with questions about `getopts` (or `getopt`, for that matter)

Comment: I wonder if it's worth it to have a full tag for both. The subjects aren't that wide anyway. Combining them into one and make one an alias for the other would be one option, but that's technically wrong and might be confusing if someone knows there's a difference. Or just [[tag:command-line-parsing]]

Comment: There is no generic `getopt` utility. There is GNU `getopt`, and there is, e.g. `getopt` on BSD systems that may not support long options at all. It would therefore be better to suggest a `gnu-getopt` tag, IMHO.

Comment: I'm torn between "are there getopt experts that would subscribe to this tag?" and "we use tags to describe many other (small) pieces of UNIX technology.  Do we want to carve out a tag for questions that happen to use getopt incidentally and/or intentionally? Would someone who's just trying to parse options in their script know to use the getopt tag? Would the site's editors?  (I'm undecided, but it's a good question/discussion to have)

Comment: maybe making getopt and getopts both aliases for the options or command-line-parsing tag would be best.

Comment: I don't think there's a GNU `getopt` command line tool either. There's the `getopt()` and `getopt_long()` functions in the GNU C library and `getopt()` is in POSIX. The feature-rich command line tool is from util-linux.

Comment: AFAIK, `getopt` in util-linux is a reimplementation of previous getopt tools which had various bugs and were unsafe to use - mostly the usual whitespace & shell metacharacter issues that plague shell scripting.